# Is there any rule of thumb to delete a variable in a large data set?

Tags: missing-data, large-data, exploratory-data-analysis

I'm working with a large set as a project for the business analytic course with $10^5$ observations and 170+ variables, some of which come with a missing value proportion of larger than 20%, even more than 95%.

I'm really thinking about under such situation, whether it's necessary to apply any imputation method to those variables rather than simply delete them.

If you could give me any criteria on how could I delete them, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to disregard variables with **some** missing data from the analysis if you find substitutes for them.

For example, if variable $X$ has some missing observations, but its non missing observations pairwise correlates with variable $Y$, then $X$ could be replaced by $Y$. It is also important to have a theoretical justification to carry on such replacement, in order to avoid spurious correlation.

There are many techniques to find correlated variables such as pairwise correlation (Pearson, Spearman), variance inflation factor (VIF), principal component analysis (PCA), clustering, etc.

If variable $Z$ has 95% of missing data, then there is not enough information even for an exploratory analysis. Better disregard it right away.